# How to mount NTFS in linux without fuseblk?

Tags: linux, kernel, ntfs, fuse

I need to check some data in linux kernel while mounting NTFS, but if I use
`mkfs.ntfs` 
or
`mkntfs`
and then
`mount -t ntfs ...`
The string containing info about file system in kernel is "fuseblk", not "ntfs" that i need.
Maybe that's because of "ntfs-3g" packs that i installed, as i know it contains fuse drivers.
How to mount NTFS without fuse?
I tried to change options in "mount" or "mkfs", but nothing helped.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be on [su] or [unix.se]

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted ntfs-3g packages and it worked as i wanted... Stranger things.